# How do I make a redirect policy on authentik and apply it to a flow without error 'flow_plan'?

Tags: python, openid-connect

I am using authentik and I want to redirect to a different website when the user logs out.
This is done by applying a policy to the last invalidation stage of the logout flow.

It seems my policy comes BEFORE the flow which is why i get 'flow_plan' not defined, and consequently context['flow'].redirect is not defined either.

How do i get the policy to come AFTER the flow in the chart?
[image: chart flow]

[image: error]

Here is the yaml for the flow:

```
context: {}
entries:
- attrs:
    authentication: none
    denied_action: message_continue
    designation: invalidation
    layout: stacked
    name: Logout
    policy_engine_mode: any
    title: Nouveau Invalidation Flow
  conditions: []
  id: null
  identifiers:
    pk: be191d0e-a41b-483b-aa79-d570ed2022bb
    slug: nouveau-invalidation-flow
  model: authentik_flows.flow
  state: present
- attrs:
    execution_logging: true
    expression: "plan = request.context.get(\"flow_plan\")\nif not plan:\n    return\
      \ False\nplan.redirect(\"https://foo.bar\")\nreturn False"
    name: nouveau-redirect-policy
  conditions: []
  id: null
  identifiers:
    pk: 68ecaf99-0d18-48bb-956b-b69df515a685
  model: authentik_policies_expression.expressionpolicy
  state: present
- attrs: {}
  conditions: []
  id: null
  identifiers:
    name: nouveau-invalidation-stage
    pk: 73056828-cff0-4ec6-af49-e72feaf1df0d
  model: authentik_stages_user_logout.userlogoutstage
  state: present
- attrs:
    invalid_response_action: retry
    policy_engine_mode: any
    re_evaluate_policies: true
  conditions: []
  id: null
  identifiers:
    order: 20
    pk: 090b0350-e22e-4f46-9010-2ae9979885b1
    stage: 73056828-cff0-4ec6-af49-e72feaf1df0d
    target: be191d0e-a41b-483b-aa79-d570ed2022bb
  model: authentik_flows.flowstagebinding
  state: present
- attrs:
    enabled: true
    group: bea3a21e-5c8e-42cf-ac80-03eb07e3c858
    timeout: 30
  conditions: []
  id: null
  identifiers:
    order: 100
    pk: fda33932-856f-41ea-9d9c-989748d19441
    policy: 68ecaf99-0d18-48bb-956b-b69df515a685
    target: be191d0e-a41b-483b-aa79-d570ed2022bb
  model: authentik_policies.policybinding
  state: present
metadata:
  labels:
    blueprints.goauthentik.io/generated: 'true'
  name: authentik Export - 2023-07-29 18:26:43.853730+00:00
version: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

1- Click on button marked in red[image]

2- Then dropdown will open up where you can add that policy[image]

Comment: Awesome! I did not notice this little arrow!